# What's the easiest/best way to debug remote processes?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using roslaunch to launch remote processes presents a bit of a challenge in debugging. Typically I use `ulimit -c unlimited` to cause any crash to emit a stack trace, however it seems as though roslaunch is not running a bash shell that executes .bashrc as no cores are being dumped. The alternative has been `launch-prefix` with `xterm` and `gdb` but obviously that won't work in this situation.

What are some ways to debug remote processes (especially ones that crash before `gdb --attach` can be called)?

(I'm running electric so env-loader is unavailable)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32309/what%27s-the-easiest/best-way-to-debug-remote-processes?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2012-04-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ended up using the info on this page:

- http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB

to set up gnuscreen in my launch file with:

```
launch-prefix="screen -d -m gdb --args"
```

And then ssh'd over to the other machine and did

```
screen -r
```

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I remember properly, a remote shell (usually bash) does get invoked before roslaunch is invoked. On some modern linux systems, particularly Ubuntu, there's a check at the beginning of the default .bashrc that exits if you're running a non-interactive shell. You should look for that and put your ulimit before it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-04-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-04-22**:
Actually, I doubt that .bashrc is loaded on remote launch. bash's man page states that .bashrc is only loaded for interactive shells. By setting the environment variable BASH_ENV using the env tag in roslaunch, it should be possible to achieve loading bashrc though.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2012-04-24**:
I wasn't able to test this since I fixed the bug causing the crash, but I did verify that .bashrc has the line in question.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If log files are not sufficient for you, you could use a proxy script that sets uname and then executes your node. It feels like an ugly hack but should work :) Such a script could look like this (untested!):

```
#!/bin/bash
uname -c unlimited
EXECUTABLE=$1
shift
exec $EXECUTABLE $@
```

When you use the script as a launch-prefix, you should get core dumps.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1